# Coherent state path integral for Dirac fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, dirac-equation, coherent-states

I’m trying to derive the fermionic path integral for the Dirac theory using the coherent state path integral, but I’m not able to get around the presence of a $\gamma_0$ making it look different from the standard result I’m used to. For a simple quantum mechanical system with a normal-ordered Hamiltonian $H(a^\dagger,a)$ in terms of one set of creation/annihilation operator, the coherent state path integral for the amplitude $\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle$ (where $\mid i,t_i \rangle = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} H(a^\dagger,a) t_i}\mid i \rangle$ and $\mid f,t_f \rangle = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} H(a^\dagger,a) t_f}\mid f \rangle$ are both Heisenberg picture states) looks like

$$\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle  = \langle f\mid e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} H(a^\dagger,a) (t_f-t_i)} \mid i \rangle = \int \mathcal{D}z \mathcal{D}\bar{z} \exp\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \left[\frac{\hbar}{2i}(z\partial_t \bar{z} - \bar{z}\partial_t z) - H(z,\bar{z})\right] e^{\frac{1}{2}(|z_i|^2+|z_f|^2)}\langle f \mid z_f\rangle\langle z_i \mid i \rangle$$

where $\mid z \rangle = e^{za^\dagger}\mid 0 \rangle$ and $\langle z \mid = \langle 0 \mid e^{\bar{z}a}$ are the coherent states, for any complex number $z$ with complex conjugate $\bar{z}$. $z_i = z(t_i)$ and $z_f = z(t_f)$. Here $H(z,\bar{z})$ is the expression obtained by formally replacing $a^\dagger$ with $\bar{z}$ and $a$ with $z$ in the expression $H(a^\dagger,a)$

The Dirac theory has a normal-ordered Hamiltonian $H(\psi_\alpha^\dagger(\mathbf{x}),\psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x})) = \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{x})\gamma_0(i\gamma_i \partial_i + m)\psi(\mathbf{x})$ in terms of the creation operators $\psi_\alpha^\dagger(\mathbf{x})$ and the annihilation operators $\psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x})$. These can be treated like creation and annihilation operators because the equal-time canonical anticommutation relations imply that
$$\{\psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x}), \psi^\dagger_\beta(\mathbf{y})\} = \psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x}) \psi^\dagger_\beta(\mathbf{y}) + \psi^\dagger_\beta(\mathbf{y}) \psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x}) = \delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$$

So, I can use the coherent state path integral, noting that now the coherent states for fermions are in terms of Grassmann fields $\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ and $\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x})$, and are given by $\mid \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\rangle = e^{-\int d^d\mathbf{x} \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\psi^\dagger_\alpha(\mathbf{x})}\mid 0\rangle$ and $\langle \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\mid = \langle 0 \mid e^{\int d^d\mathbf{x} \bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x})}$. Since $\psi_\alpha(x) \mid \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\rangle = \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\mid \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\rangle$ and $\langle \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\mid \psi_\alpha^\dagger(x) = \langle \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})\mid  \bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}) $, the derivation of the coherent state path integral should be similar, and would produce

$$\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle = \int \mathcal{D}\zeta \mathcal{D}\bar{\zeta} \exp\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \left[\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\int d^d\mathbf{x}\hspace{2pt}\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\partial_t \bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t) - \bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\partial_t \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\right) - H(\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x}),\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}))\right] \times e^{\frac{1}{2}(\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})+\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}))}\langle f \mid \zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\rangle\langle \zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}) \mid i \rangle$$

Here $\zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}) = \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t_i)$ and $\zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x}) = \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t_f)$ and $H(\zeta(\mathbf{x}),\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}))$ is obtained by formally replacing $\psi_\alpha^\dagger(\mathbf{x})$ with $\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ and $\psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ with $\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ in the normal-ordered expression $H(\psi_\alpha^\dagger(\mathbf{x}), \psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x}))$. But, making this formal replacement, I obtain

$$\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle = \int \mathcal{D}\zeta \mathcal{D}\bar{\zeta} \exp\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \left[\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\int d^d\mathbf{x}\hspace{2pt}\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\partial_t \bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t) - \bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\partial_t \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\right) - H(\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x}),\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}))\right] \times e^{\frac{1}{2}(\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})+\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}))}\langle f \mid \zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\rangle\langle \zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}) \mid i \rangle$$

Integrate by parts:

$$\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle = \int \mathcal{D}\zeta \mathcal{D}\bar{\zeta} \exp\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \left[i\hbar\left(\int d^d\mathbf{x}\hspace{2pt}\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\partial_t \zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t)\right) - H(\zeta_\alpha(\mathbf{x}),\bar{\zeta}_\alpha(\mathbf{x}))\right] \times e^{\frac{1}{2}(\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})+\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}))}\langle f \mid \zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\rangle\langle \zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}) \mid i \rangle$$

Make the replacement:

$$\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle = \int \mathcal{D}\zeta \mathcal{D}\bar{\zeta} \exp\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \left[\int d^d\mathbf{x}\hspace{2pt} \bar{\zeta}(\mathbf{x},t)\gamma_0(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\zeta(\mathbf{x},t)\right] \times e^{\frac{1}{2}(\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})+\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}))}\langle f \mid \zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\rangle\langle \zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}) \mid i \rangle$$

While the standard result I’ve seen does not have the extra $\gamma_0$ above. This would seem to imply the formal replacement is $\bar{\psi} \leftrightarrow \bar{\zeta}$, but looking at the derivation of the coherent state path integral, it seems like it must be the creation operator $\psi^\dagger$ that is replaced by Grassmann $\bar{\zeta}$, not the adjoint $\bar{\psi} = \psi^\dagger\gamma_0$. How is it that we can write

$$\langle f,t_f \mid i,t_i \rangle = \int \mathcal{D}\zeta \mathcal{D}\bar{\zeta} \exp\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \left[\int d^d\mathbf{x}\hspace{2pt} \bar{\zeta}(\mathbf{x},t)(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\zeta(\mathbf{x},t)\right] \times e^{\frac{1}{2}(\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})+\bar{\zeta}_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x})\zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}))}\langle f \mid \zeta_{\alpha,f}(\mathbf{x})\rangle\langle \zeta_{\alpha,i}(\mathbf{x}) \mid i \rangle$$

without the extra $\gamma_0$?

Comment: Could it be that the independence of the Grassmann variables allows me to define $\bar{\xi}’ = \bar{\xi}\gamma_0$, and then let $\xi$ and $\bar{\xi}’$ be four pairs of Grassmann variables, redefine the coherent states, and then end up with the  path integral expression without the $\gamma_0$?